# How to hightlight a react-native map like that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps library to show the map, but how do I highlight a region like this screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [Polygon](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polygon.md).

1. You need to provide the coordinates of the area that you want to highlight.
2. Put all coordinates in an array.
3. A coordinate will be connected to its previous coordinate with a straight line. In case of the image you posted, you need a looooot of coordinates. I personally don't know any public API that returns an array of coordinates of a desired area, but I'm sure there is one, just google it.

Once you have the coordinates in an array, use them like this in your `MapView`:

```
<MapView>
  <MapView.Polygon
    coordinates={[
      { latitude: 123, longitude: 123 },
      { latitude: 124, longitude: 124 },
      ...
    ]}
    strokeWidth={1}        // The width of the outline of the shape
    strokeColor='#4099FF'  // Color of the outline
    fillColor='rgba(...)'  // Shape color
  />
</MapView>
```

Comment: Thank you it's helpful. Could you also check my question as well? thank you very much -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76210545/how-to-use-polygon-more-effectively-on-react-native-maps